# How view engine works in MVC for same view page with different path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I have created two plugins named for example as CustomPlugin & MyPlugin. Both plugin have that page with **same name**. e.g. xyz.cshtml. But have different model. E.g means CustomPlugin has xyz.cshtml with its model and MyPlugin has xyz.cshtml with its own model. I use View engine in both of these plugins. I have registered View Engine on 0 index in both plugins.

I want to know which plugin call that view page first? How View Engine works if it has two path for 0 index? Is there any way to make it first always?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have mentation that you have common view page but model is different so it means in each plugin you have put that viewpage but model is common or you have make only single file which call both plugin with different model.?

Comment: Please look here, if you are passing different model that try this  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views here they show how to pass dynamic model to view ... may be this helps you

Comment: Both plugin have that page with **same name**. e.g. xyz.cshtml. But have different model. E.g means CustomPlugin has xyz.cshtml with its model and MyPlugin has xyz.cshtml with its own model.

Comment: ok then why you phase issue if both plugin are different and why you use view engine..?

Comment: I use view engine so that I do not need to put that view page manually in Nop.Web/Views folder

Comment: ok.... but you can also give a full path in action result return view("view.cshtml", model)..... no need to make sparate view engine

Comment: And what if customers want to use plugin's view pages in their theme. The solution you gave is not right.

Comment: Does the nop.web or any theme Folder has the same view?

Comment: @batmaci : Yes, but that is not a problem. The only problem is with same page in different plugin. But model is different

Comment: You views will be called by route which has a unique namespace and view and Periority. ViewEngines won't cause any problem. ViewEngine only instructs where to find view.But during searching for a view, ViewEngine uses controller name from RouteData which is provided by routing system.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is not with the Views but with Controllers. In general MVC is routed through controllers not with Views. That means routes in the  RouteProvider.cs for each Plugin are defining which Contoller/View is executed first. 
Default Routes have priority 0 in the Presentation\Nop.Web\Infrastructure\RouteProvider.cs class if you check the buttom of the class with the lines

```
public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

You should define same routeprovider.cs inside your plugin and set it is Priority higher than 0. Respectively set other one higher than other plugin if you want it to be executed first. Then inside each routeproider place a call/insert for your Custom View Engine as below.

```
    public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)            {

                    System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0,new CustomViewEngine());

  // your routes for your plugin here

}
```

It adds additional locations for the ViewEngine to search for Views and will ensure that will look first inside it is own View directory by Inserting in the position 0. So out of these 2 plugins later called "routeprovider.cs" will be in the first position. It means lower the routeprovide priority has higher the view location (or priority)
But there can be a problem here. Since you have same named View. I believe that you will get problem because you cant manage 2 plugins (controllers) find dynamically 2 different Views unless you hard code the routing in the controller. Because ViewEngine registration will search through all registered views and it will route the view it finds first.

> what if customers want to use plugin's view pages in their theme

I dont see any problem here. Because purpose of Plugins are to override default controllers, views or add additional features. Therefore as I wrote above priority should be higher in the RouteProviders of the Plugins. See the configure.cshtml and related configure action for each plugin. this is how they work. every plugin has same configure.cshtml and it will be called as  return View("~/Plugins/DiscountRules.CustomerRoles/Views/DiscountRulesCustomerRoles/Configure.cshtml", model); for example

**UPDATE:** multiple theme is difficult issue for the plugins because plugin usually overrides all available themes including default one if position is inserted as 0 as above. if you are overriding entire view, you can use    System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.Add, this will make sure that theme view wins, if it exist and the ones should use the plugin view, they shouldn't have the same named view under the theme. For example,

- PLugin - abc.cshtml
- Theme 1- abc.cshtml
- Theme 2 - no abc.cshtml

In this case Theme 1 uses it is own, theme 2 uses from plugin. **But this case only works when models are the same** because you cant make controller optional for the same route.

If you are overriding a partialview or some html in the view, you can use widget + api plugin. widget makes the routing, api plugin implements that route.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can not write full path in my plugin, because if I do so I do not need to right view engine and by writing full path it will always find page in plugin's Views folder. And this will cause an issue if someone use multiple Theme in their site. How they will add changes to support their multiple themes.

Comment: @Ankita your question is different than your comment now :) "I want to know which plugin call that view page first? How View Engine works if it has two path for 0 index? Is there any way to make it first always?". anyhow please see my updated answer. I guess you have different controller action, different view, different model and you want these to be optional by theme. As my experience tells me this is not easily possible. I just wrote the possibilities above. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but as far I know widget is to create widget zones which we use lateron to display things to that location. How we can implement routing using it? Can you please explore it as well? Else is there any document for the same???

Comment: Moreover, if I use Add function it will add my path to the end of the list which nopCommerce provide & it will find my partial page at theme location. And as my page has its own model mapped it gives error for model like getting model is this and expected is this.

Comment: @Ankita regarding widget, thats how I used as well but I believe if you want to change a bigger are, you can pretend it like partialview. For that you need to use an api get the data with json as widget doesnt have a model. As I wrote above, you shouldnt have same named view on theme and it gets it from plugin and models cant be different unfortunately if you wont other theme contrarily should use its own view. I see that some error in my update. I fix it above. please read it again.